# Location Manager not displaying Latitude, Longitude, or Altitude

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I have an application that after asking for the users location displays the lat/long, and altitude in labels.

It then takes the lat/long and uses reverse geocoding to turn them into an address that is then displayed in labels as well.

However, with my current code I can't get both to work at the same time. That is right now geocoding will work, but the lat/long and altitude won't be displayed, and if I comment out the section on reverse geocoding, they display just fine.

I've looked for a solution and have not found any to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I figure it has something to do with two updatelocation methods, but I can't figure out what to change.

```
#import "LocationDataViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface LocationDataViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@end



@implementation LocationDataViewController
@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize libraryButton;
@synthesize cameraButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //gets current location as soon as user allows location sharing
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    _startLocation = nil;

    }



- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{



}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)onBack:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}




//Displays lat/long

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                 newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _latitude.text = currentLatitude;

    NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                  newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _longitude.text = currentLongitude;



    NSString *currentAltitude = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithFormat:@"%+.6f",
                                 newLocation.altitude];
    _altitude.text = currentAltitude;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.strLocationLat = currentLatitude;
    appDelegate.strLocationLong = currentLongitude;


}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

//turns lat/long into address

#pragma mark - actions

- (IBAction)findCurrentAddress:(id)sender
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        if(_locationManager==nil)
        {
            _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            _locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;
            _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
            _locationManager.delegate = self;

        }

        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        self.address.text = @"Getting location...";
    }
    else
    {
        self.address.text=@"Location services are unavailable";
    }
}

#pragma mark - delegate methods for geocoder

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

    // Make sure this is a recent location event
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSTimeInterval eventInterval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if(abs(eventInterval) < 30.0)
    {
        // Make sure the event is valid
        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
            return;

        // Instantiate _geoCoder if it has not been already
        if (_geocoder == nil)
            _geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        //Only one geocoding instance per action
        //so stop any previous geocoding actions before starting this one
        if([_geocoder isGeocoding])
            [_geocoder cancelGeocode];

        [_geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: newLocation
                        completionHandler: ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
         {
             if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
             {
                 CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                 NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                 placemark.addressDictionary;


                 self.address.text =[addressDictionary
                                    objectForKey:
                                    (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];

                 self.city.text = [addressDictionary
                                   objectForKey:
                                   (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];


                 self.state.text = [addressDictionary
                                    objectForKey:
                                    (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];


                self.zip.text = [addressDictionary
                                  objectForKey:
                                  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];


             }
         }];

        //Stop updating location until they click the button again
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}





@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using both a deprecated method and the new method for different things...

Copy all the code in:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Into this one:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

And then remove the first one. As far as I know, if you've got the second one implemented, the system won't bother calling the first one since it's deprecated and they do the same thing anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so when I try this I get an error that says "use of undeclared identifier newlocation, and suggests fixing it by making it CLLocation.  When I do that, it then says that property cooridnate is not found on object type 'cllocation'